What is causing the error `Cannot access '<init>': it is package-private in 'Icon'`?
It's occurring in the following code:
Scaffold(
    floatingActionButton = {
        FloatingActionButton(onClick = {}) {
            Icon(Icons.Default.Add, contentDescription = "Add")
        }
    },
    bottomBar = {
        BottomAppBar(
            actions = {
                IconButton(onClick = {}) {
                    Icon(Icons.Filled.Edit)
                }
            }
        )
    }
)

In IconButton, Icon is underlined with the following error: Cannot access '<init>': it is package-private in 'Icon' and Icons.Filled.Edit is underlined with the following error: Too many arguments for public/*package*/ constructor Icon() defined in android.graphics.drawable.Icon. The icon in the FloatingActionButton is not throwing an error.
For the icon, I have the imports:
import androidx.compose.material3.Icon
import androidx.compose.material.icons.Icons


The error message mentions android.graphics.drawable.Icon, not the Icon from androidx.compose.material3 which you said you imported. Did you also import android.graphics.drawable.Icon? Also, it seems like you also need to pass a contentDescription.

I think you import the wrong library. or you need to add contentDescription. So your code look like - Icon(Icons.Filled.Edit, contentDescription = "Edit Icon")

You need to add contentDescription parameter:
...
Icon(Icons.Default.Edit, contentDescription = "Edit")
...

it is a mandatory parameter.

That does seem to fix it, but that's so silly — the error doesn't say anything about that.
